# DELETE/INSERT INTO/ UPDATE on dynamic table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have problem with my project.

This is my code:

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->

Private Sub BtnSimpanMysql_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSimpanMySql.Click
    CbbKelas.SelectedItem = " '" & CbbKelas.SelectedItem.ToString() & "' "
    For baris As Integer = 0 To DGV.Rows.Count - 1
        konek()
        Dim hapusdb As New MySqlDataAdapter("DELETE FROM '" & CbbKelas.SelectedItem.ToString() & "' WHERE no = '" & DGV.Rows(baris).Cells(0).Value & "'", conn)
        Dim isi As New DataTable
        hapusdb.Fill(isi)
    Next baris
    DGV.Refresh()
```

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2:**

[image]

I want to *DELETE/INSERT INTO/UPDATE* my data to dynamic table with combo box options. So it will *DELETE/INSERT INTO/UPDATE* while I chose table name on combo box.

Comment: I think you forgot the python and php tags.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  `I have problem` is not very descriptive.  And always use SQL parameters rather than concatenating strings.  Always.

Comment: Do you even have a table named 1A? You should figure out proper SQL syntax by making direct queries using something like phpmyadmin or MySQL Workbench first and then worry about dynamically creating it in VB. You may want to use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`, too.

Comment: Definitely look at using something like MySQL Workbench and write the query in that. Then you can look at porting the correct syntax into VB.NET once you have it working. Use parameters as suggested. That will rule out a lot of issues in itself. Examples of how can be found all over the Internet.

Comment: I see a problem - you've surrounded your table name with single quotes. Remove that